# How to receive messages from ejabberd in node-xmpp?

Tags: node.js, ejabberd, node-xmpp

I can send messages **to** ejabberd, but how receive - i have no idea. Maybe someone has live example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is using "stanza" event. Here is example:

```
cl.addListener('stanza', function(stanza) {
    connection.write(stanza.children[1].children);
    console.log(stanza.children[1].children);
});
```